# Find the kth eleven-non-free number

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Let's define `eleven-non-free` numbers:

If we consider a number as a string, then if any substring inside is a (non-zero) power of `11`, then this number is an `eleven-non-free` number.

For example, `1123` is an `eleven-non-free` number as `11` inside is `11^1`. Also `12154` is one as `121` is `11^2`. But `12345` is not, because we can't find any *non-zero power of `11`* inside.

So given a k, find the kth `eleven-non-free` number. For example the 13th such number is `211`.

I don't know how to efficiently do it. the brute-force way is to increase i from 1 and check every number and count until the kth.

I guess we should consider strings with different length (1, 2, 3, 4, ...). then for each length, we try to fill in 11, 11^2, 11^3, etc and try to get all the combinations.

But it seems quite complicated as well.

Anyone?

Comment: Have you written any code to try to solve this? Also, I'm not opposed to purely academic questions, but you'd probably get more answers if you could describe a practical use for this.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard it is actually an mutation of http://projecteuler.net/problem=442. It is not necessarily an academic question, think of interview questions, many of them you will never need for practical

Comment: Your comment on strings of different length sounds about right. It will get complicated but I suspect if you try to just do it in ordered steps it shouldn't be too hard. Also I'm intrigued, is this just a theoretical exercise or do these eleven-non-free numbers have a purpose?

Comment: @JacksonTale: "think of **bad** interview questions that you will never need for practical purposes" - fixed it for you. ;-)

Comment: @Chris it is a mutation of http://projecteuler.net/problem=442

Comment: @Chris it depends really. For example, **bad** interview question like `how many windows in New York` has its purpose though not practical.

Comment: It's not much of a mutation: any way that you can efficiently find the nth `eleven-non-free` number will also be a way to find the nth `eleven-free-number`--just subtract the number of `eleven-non-free-numbers` from the total number you're at.

Comment: Also if you have a solution to that problem then you presumably can trivially derive a solution to this one. And with respect to interview questions I would consider bad any question that is a test of something you are never going to have to do (or indeed do something of a similar sort).

Comment: @JustinBlank true, I guess find the kth `element-non-free` is easier.

Comment: @Chris No, I don't have solution for that problem. Instead, I guess solving the question here is the way to solve that one

Comment: I would probably take the opposite approach from your brute force idea. It's still brute force, but it's easier to exploit certain symmetries. Start with a large bitmap with each bit representing an integer (e.g. using a 64KB chunk of memory to represent the first 512K integers). Set all bits to 1, then start turning off the bits that are not eleven-non-free - i.e. 11, 110-119, 211, 311, 411, etc... Then 121, 1210-1219, 2121, 3121, 4121, ....

Comment: I don't have an answer, and if I did, I'm not supposed to share. However, here's an observation I've been thinking about: 

Consider a string like `123`, you can systematically find and count the number of ways to complete that into an `eleven-free` or `eleven-non-free` string. You can do that without directly enumerating them (or rather, you don't have to necessarily enumerate them for each starting string).

Comment: @twalberg it is the similar idea as my intuition of string. But the problem is `1211` will be counted twice

Comment: @JustinBlank Why you are not supposed to share?

Comment: @JacksonTale Yes, but if you've already turned the bit off, turning it off again isn't going to hurt anything. At the end you'll have a bitmap where each 1 represents one of the numbers you're looking for...

Comment: @twalberg Maybe you can construct an answer out of your thoughts. I guess that will be more easily understandable for me.

Comment: Project Euler questions are supposed to be your own work. Publicly posting answers is discouraged. 

Btw: thank you for posting this. I haven't done anything in Project Euler for awhile, and the > 200 questions are usually too hard for me, but I think I can solve this one.

Comment: @JustinBlank Yeah, I know. that's why I didn't directly ask tbh.

Comment: Has anyone solved the 1 quintilian string interrogations part of the problem? :)

Comment: @Jackson Tale - You may have seen that I solved the Euler version of your question. I didn't post the answer to the problem specifically. But, I did post the working algorithm. Do you think I should remove the algorithm and only leave behind the conceptual information? Your input would be appreciated.

Comment: @drankin2112 u mean you remove teh algorithm just incase projecteuler doesn't want answer to be public?

Comment: Yes. I enjoyed the challenge but I'm not looking to upset anyone. But, I'd also like people to try and understand how it works. Doing so will help them solve problems like this on their own. Maybe I should invert the algorithm and post the results for only the non-11-free numbers instead of the 11-free ones. What do you think is most appropriate? I'm open. I'm just proud to have got it. It kicked my butt. I just about gave up.

Comment: @drankin2112 I guess maybe you can post the results for only the 11-non-free ones as asked by this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, this took several days to figure out. The first important thing to understand is that the only concrete requirement of the euler puzzle 442 that this question stems from is to solve for E(10^18). The unrelated examples of what an 11-free number means are just distractions.

The brute force option is out of the question, for 2 reasons.

1. It requires literally a quintilian string comparisons and would take a week to resolve on most home computers.
2. Leonhard Euler was a mathematician so the spirit of the question has to be interpreted in that context.

After a while, I started focusing on pattern matching for powers of 10, instead of continually including powers of 11 in my algorithms. After you calculate what the powers of 11 are, you're done with anything related to that. They only represent strings. They aren't even included in the final algorithm, they are just used in the detective work.

I started trying to get a detailed understanding of how new 11-containing numbers are introduced between powers of 10 and if there was a predictable pattern. If there was, then it would just be a matter of using that pattern to deduce all of the 11-containing numbers introduced prior to any 10^ stopping point.

### Understanding the Main Concepts

For each new 10^ reached, the number of previous 11^ string matches are identical to the previous 10^ range. It's easier to explain with a chart.

Here is a list of 10^2 - 10^6 that shows the count of new 11-containing numbers introduced so far and grouped by the 11^ number that matched the string.

**Fig 1.)** Number of 11^ matches in 10^ ranges grouped by 11^ string match

```
---------------------------
10^2 range (10 - 100)
---------------------------
    11            1
---------------------------
10^3 range (100 - 1000)
---------------------------
    11           18
    121           1
---------------------------
10^4 range (1000 - 10000)
---------------------------
    11          260
    121          18
    1331          1
---------------------------
10^5 range (10000 - 100000)
---------------------------
    11         3392
    121         260
    1331         18
    14641         1
---------------------------
10^6 range (100000 - 1000000)
---------------------------
    11        41760
    121        3392
    1331        260
    14641        18
    161051        1

etc...
```

There are two requirements for making this list.

1. When multiple 11-containing numbers are match sequentially (like 11000 - 11999) all of those items must be attributed to the 11^ group of the first match. Meaning that even though there will be matches for 121 and 1331 in that example, all matches in that range are attributed to 11, because it is first.
2. Matches are made based on the shortest possibility first. i.e.) 11, 121, 1331, etc... This is because some numbers match multiple 11^ strings while others appear inside of a contiguous range. And, matching them from high to low doesn't produce a predictable pattern. Functionally, it's all the same. This just brings a whole lot of clarity into the picture.

Notice that in each new 10^ range, only 1 new 11^ match is introduced. And, the number of matches for each previous 11^ number is identical, regardless of the previous power. The difficulty here is that the number of *11 string matches can't be directly inferred from the previous power.

**Fig 2.)** Differentiating other 11^ patterns from the *11 match

```
    ****11
    ***110 pattern
    **1100 pattern
    *11000 pattern
    110000 pattern
    etc...
```

All of the "pattern" matches are highly predictable within 10^ powers. Only the *11 numbers are not obvious in how they accumulate. It's not really that there isn't a pattern, the problem is that you would have to presume numbers that were scanned right to left and, as a result, none if the other patterns would be predictable anymore.

As it turns out, a separate accumulator has to be tracked concurrently that allows us to use the previous *11 matches to calculate the number of new *11 matches. For any of you math geniuses out there, there may be a more elegant solution. But, here is mine.

You have to always be separately keeping track of the number of *11 matches from the **previous  2** powers. Using these as operands, you can calculate the number of *11 matches for the current power.

Example:

The number of *11 matches in the 10^3 range is 8. There are also 10 matches on "110" but they don't matter here, we are just tracking numbers that end with "11". So, we are starting with the 2 previous *11 match counts being 8 and 0 from the **2 previous** 10^ ranges.

**Important:** For any number less than 10^2, 0 is the previous match count for this calculation. That is why 0 is the second look-back operand when working with 10^3.

**Fig 3.)** How to calculate *11 match counts per 10^ range using back-tracking

```
    10^3 |   80 = 8 * 10 - 0;
    10^4 |  792 = 80 * 10 - 8;
    10^5 | 7840 = 792 * 10 - 80;
```

This number however is only useful by looking at it, again, from a different perspective.

**Fig 4.)** Illustration of how match groups scale by powers of 10

```
    ==================================
      #    Formulas for 10^4
    ==================================
     80    **11         = 8 * 10 - 0
     80    *110 pattern = previous power's *11 times 10
    100    1100 pattern = previous power's 110 times 10
    ==================================
    260   Total matches in range

    ==================================
       #  Formulas for 10^5
    ==================================
     792  ***11         = 80 * 10 - 8
     800  **110 pattern = previous power's **11 times 10
     800  *1100 pattern = previous power's *110 times 10
    1000  11000 pattern = previous power's 1100 times 10
    ==================================
    3392  Total matches in range
```

In these examples, only the *11 number has to be calculated separately. Seeing these numbers stacked like this sort of makes it feel more complicated than it is. It's only important to understand the concept. In practice, we abstract out everything except the *11 calculation through cumulative multiplication.

Now, before we get into a working algorithm, the last thing to understand conceptually is how to use these patterns to calculate the Nth 11-free number ending at each ^10.

This is a two step process so I'll demonstrate using an example. Lets look at the 1000 - 10000 range from Fig 1. 10000 is 10^4 so that is the range we are solving for.

The following 11^ groups are all within that range. The 18 and the 1 can be derived from the previous powers (see Fig 1).

```
    match         #
    ---------------
    11          260
    121          18
    1331          1
```

1. Calculate the total 11-containing matches in the current 10^4 range. To do this, we first have to calculate the value for the "11" match category. The 260 value above can be calculated using numbers from **both** the previous ranges and the separate *11 tracking operands like so:

   Calculating *11 count for 10^4

   ```
       260 = (18 * 10) + (8 * 10 - 0)
   ```

   - Where 18 is the total of all "11" matches (not necessarily *11) from the 10^3 range (see Fig 1).
   - The 10's are constants.
   - And, 8 and 0 are our starting points, mentioned previously, for separately calculating *11 changes.
2. Combine the result of 10^4 with all the other results back to 10^2. **Note:** The total matches for 10^2 is 1 because there is only one 11-containing number from 0 through 100.

   ```
   Total 11-containing numbers in 10^4 range:  279 = 260 + 18 + 1
   Total 10^4 range plus previous totals    :  299 = 279 + 19 + 1
                                              ---------------------
                                 10^4 solved: 9701 = 10^4 - 299
   ```

### A Working Algorithm

Here is an algorithm written in C# that solves for each of 10^1 through 10^18. It returns almost instantly. Out of respect for project euler I didn't post the answer to their puzzle directly. The output is accurate though. Right now the #442 question only shows 163 people have solved the problem compared to 336260 people solving problem #1. If that number starts growing for no reason, I will delete this post.

```
    private ulong GetNthElevenFreeForPow10(uint pow){

        if(pow > 18)
            throw new ArgumentException("Argument must be a positive integer between 1 and 18", "pow");

        // All of the numbers up to 10^0 & 10^1 are 11-free
        // if 1 is considered 11-free as the euler question 
        // states.
        if (pow == 0 || pow == 1)
            return (ulong)Math.Pow(10, pow);

        // The sequence of 11s doesn't form a repeatable pattern
        // until 10^4 because it requires back tracking to 
        // calculated running totals.
        if (pow == 2)
            return (ulong)Math.Pow(10, pow) - 1;

        if (pow == 3)
            return (ulong)Math.Pow(10, pow) - (18 + 1 + 1);

        // At each new power the number of elevens created is 
        // easily predicted based on the previous power. But, 
        // the number of new entries ending with 11 i.e.) xxx11
        // is a little trickier. It requires a lookback at the 
        // two previous powers. This array stores the lookback 
        // operands used to make that calculation.
        ulong[] lookbackOperands = new ulong[] { 
            0, 8
        };

        // this number is used to calculate all of the new 11-containing 
        // numbers for each power. The next power is always a calculation 
        // on the previous.
        ulong elevensConsumedCurrent = 18;
        ulong elevensConsumedPrevious = 18 + 1;

        // this number holds a running total all 11-containing
        // numbers consumed so far.
        ulong elevensConsumedTotal = 20;

        for (int n = 4; n <= pow; n++) {
            // Calculate the number of new items added that end with "11".
            ulong endsWith11Current = lookbackOperands[1] * 10 - lookbackOperands[0];
            lookbackOperands[0] = lookbackOperands[1];
            lookbackOperands[1] = endsWith11Current;

            elevensConsumedCurrent = elevensConsumedCurrent * 10 + endsWith11Current;
            elevensConsumedPrevious += elevensConsumedCurrent;
            elevensConsumedTotal += elevensConsumedPrevious;
        }

        return (ulong)Math.Pow(10, pow) - elevensConsumedTotal;

    }
```

Usage:

```
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (uint n = 1; n <= 18; n++)
            sb.AppendLine(String.Format(
                    "Nth 11-Free Number @ 10^{0}\t{1}", 
                    n, 
                    GetNthElevenFreeForPow10(n).ToString()
                )
            );

        Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```

Here are the first 15.

```
Nth 11-Free Number @ 10^1   10
Nth 11-Free Number @ 10^2   99
Nth 11-Free Number @ 10^3   980
Nth 11-Free Number @ 10^4   9701
Nth 11-Free Number @ 10^5   96030
Nth 11-Free Number @ 10^6   950599
Nth 11-Free Number @ 10^7   9409960
Nth 11-Free Number @ 10^8   93149001
Nth 11-Free Number @ 10^9   922080050
Nth 11-Free Number @ 10^10  9127651499
Nth 11-Free Number @ 10^11  90354434940
Nth 11-Free Number @ 10^12  894416697901
Nth 11-Free Number @ 10^13  8853812544070
Nth 11-Free Number @ 10^14  87643708742799
Nth 11-Free Number @ 10^15  867583274883920
```

Answer (score 2):

It's interesting how easily people get scared by the term *"brute force"* without even trying to quantify it :)

#### Brute force solution is actually O(R * log R)

where R is the result (`k`-th eleven-non-free number). You just test all numbers 1..R and for each of them you perform string searches for 11, 121, 1331, 14641 etc. using prepared automaton (for given number of digits). **`O(R * log R)` doesn't look that bad**, if you look at it this way, does it? :-)

#### Generation solution?

Clever idea is to try to generate the number more directly:

1. either by generating **directly** the `k`-th number;
2. or by **sequentially** generating all 1-`k` eleven-non-free numbers;
3. or by generating **all** eleven-non-free numbers < 10^n at once and sort them up.

Solution 1 would have to be *very* clever, if not close to impossible. Solution 2 seems better than brute force solution because it skips those numbers which are not eleven-non-free. Solution 3 would be an easily implemented alternative, which brings us to important question:

#### How many eleven-non-free numbers < 10<sup>n</sup> exist?

Easy combinatorics (works exactly for n <= 10; for higher n it is close approximation, neglecting that 11<sup>2</sup> is substring of 11<sup>13</sup> and 11 is substring of 11<sup>11</sup> and 11<sup>19</sup>):

[image]

so basicly for the limit 10<sup>n</sup> you get more than 10<sup>n-2</sup> solutions! This means that number of solutions is a constant proportion of the limit, which means that

#### O(R) = O(k)

which implies that

### The brute force solution is actually O(k * log k), as well as the *generate-all* solution!

The dreaded brute force solution kooks much much better now, doesn't it? Yet it's still the same :)

#### Can we get better than this?

- Solution 1 - would be a chance, but close to magic.
- Solution 2 - the best you can hope for is `O(k)` but you would have to be very careful to achieve this. There will be many complications that will make it uneasy to select next smallest eleven-non-free-number. E.g. when generating all 11xxx, 121xx, 1331x, eg. 13121 falls in between, making any automatic generation of *ordered* numbers difficult, let alone duplicities caused by pattern appearing in xxx digits etc. You will probably end up with some complicated data structure that will force `O(log k)` in each step, and thus `O(k log k)` in total.
- Solution 3 - this we already know is `O(k log k)`, which is the same as to find `k`-th number.

Comment: Good! I never got around to fixing up my answer and now I don't have to. ;)

Comment: No, don't use brute force -- there's an O(polylog(k))-time algorithm. Perhaps someone else will be in the mood to post spoilers about it.

Comment: Dynamic programming works here.  Finding the k'th eleven-non-free number is closely related to counting the number of eleven-non-free numbers of a given length, which is the kind of thing DP is good at.  See my answer below, for example.

Comment: I see that you are genuinely interested in a better solution for the eleven-non-free number question. I solved the Euler version and posted it but I'm probably gonna delete it soon. I feel guilty for posting it. I'm not looking to offend anyone who wants the answer to be secret. So if your interested it's there for now. BTW. I'm jealous that you can back into algebraic equations from source code. Anyhow, take care.

Comment: @drankin2112 I +1 your solution. Why would you have to delete it? It's your work and you have full author rights over it!

Comment: @Tomas - Yeah, I know. But, for me it was really more about the challenge than anything else. The more I think about it though, the only prize you get from a site like projecteuler.net is the satisfaction of knowing you solved the questions. Why would anyone try to cheat anyhow? We'll see how it goes. Thanks for +1. Back at ya.

Answer (score 2):

As good starting point is to consider the related problem of counting how many eleven-non-free (ENF) integers there are of N digits.  This is not exactly the same thing as finding the n'th ENF integer, but the latter problem can be reduced to the former pretty easily (see the end of this post for java code that does this).

The idea is to do dynamic programming on prefixes.  For any string of digits `s`, and any integer `k`, let `N(k,s)` denote the number of ENF strings of length `k` which start with `s`.  And, for any string `s`, let `s_0` be the longest suffix of `s` that also occurs as a prefix of any power of eleven (POE) of length `k` or less.  Then, assuming that `s` itself does not contain any POE substrings, we have the equation:

```
N(k,s) = N(k-length(s)+length(s_0),s_0)
```

The reasoning behind this equation is as follows.  Since `s_0` is a suffix of `s`, let us write `s` as a concatenation of some other string `q` and `s_0`: `s=[q,s_0]`.  Now, let `r` be any digit string which starts with `s` and again let us write this as a concatenation, as `r=[s,r_0] = [q,s_0,r_0]`.

If `r` contains a POE as a substring, then either this POE is contained in `r_0`, or else it crosses over the boundary between `s` and `r_0`.  In this case, `s` must end in a POE prefix, and, since we know that the longest POE prefix that occurs as a suffix of `s` is `s_0`, it follows that if `r` contains a POE substring, then this substring must be contained in `[s_0,r_0]`.  This gives us a one-to-one correspondence between ENFs that begin with `s=[q,s_0]` and ENFs that begin with `s_0`.

This above equation gives rise to a recursive algorithm to count the number of k-digit ENFs with a given prefix.  The base cases end up being instances where `length(s_0)=length(s)` which means that `s` itself is a prefix of a POE of length k or less.  Since there aren't very many such POE prefixes (at most k choose 2 which is O(k^2)), this formula leads to an efficient algorithm.  Here is pseudocode:

```
Given a prefix s and an integer k, this function computes N(k,s)

if s contains a POE then return 10^(k-length(s))
if length(s) = k return 0 
let s0 = longest POE prefix which is a suffix of s
if(length(s0)<length(s))
  return N(k-length(s)+length(s0),s0)
total = 0
for d = "0" to "9"
  total += N(k,concatenate(s,d))
return total
```

Using dynamic programming, the running time of this algorithm will be polynomial in k, the number of digits.  The algorithm only recurses on POE prefixes, and since there are O(k^2) of these, the running time will be O(k^2) times the running time of each iteration.  Using a naive O(k^2) algorithm to find the longest suffix that matches a POE prefix would thus lead to an O(k^4) algorithm, while using a radix tree to find matches in linear time would result in O(k^3).  The java code given below uses the naive algorithm, and experimentally, for values up to around k=100 seems to be Θ(k^4.5), though this discrepancy could well be due to implementation details or constant factors affecting runtimes for small input sizes.  Here is the code:

```
public class Eleven {

  public static final String[] digits = 
    {"0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"};

  public static BigInteger countENF(String prefix, int k){
    return countENF(prefix,k,new HashMap(),getPowers(k));
  }

  public static BigInteger countENF(String prefix, 
      int k, 
      // This map contains stored results for dynamic programming
      // Pair is an auxiliary class that does what you think it does
      Map<Pair<String,Integer>,BigInteger> resultMap,
      // precomputed list of powers of 11
      List<String> powers
      ){
    // Dynamic programming case
    BigInteger res = resultMap.get(new Pair(prefix,k));
    if(res != null)
      return res;

    // base cases
    if(!isEFree(prefix, powers)){
      res = new BigInteger("10").pow(k-prefix.length());
      resultMap.put(new Pair<>(prefix,k), res);
      return res;
    }
    if(prefix.length() >= k){
      res = new BigInteger("0");
      resultMap.put(new Pair<>(prefix,k), res);
      return res;
    }    
    String s0 = getMaxPrefix(prefix, powers);
    if(s0.length() < prefix.length()){
      return countENF(s0,k+s0.length()-prefix.length(),resultMap,powers);
    }

    // recursive summation
    res = new BigInteger("0");
    for(String d : digits){
      String s1 = prefix + d;
      res = res.add(countENF(s1,k,resultMap,powers));
    }
    resultMap.put(new Pair<>(prefix, k), res);
    return res;
  }  


  //
  // helper functions
  //

  // returns all POEs of at most length digits
  private static List<String> getPowers(int length) {
    List<String> ret = new ArrayList<>();
    BigInteger val = new BigInteger("11");
    BigInteger eleven = new BigInteger("11");
    while(val.toString().length() <= length){
      ret.add(val.toString());
      val = val.multiply(eleven);
    }
    return ret;
  }

  // finds the longest string that is both a prefix of s and a suffix of a POE
  private static String getMaxSuffix(String s, List<String> powers){
    for(int i=s.length(); i>0; i--){
      String sub = s.substring(0,i);
      for(String p : powers){
        if(p.endsWith(sub))
          return sub;
      }
    }
    return "";
  }

  public static boolean isEFree(String s, List<String> powers){
    for(String p : powers){
      if(s.indexOf(p)>=0)
        return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
```

As mentioned above, this algorithm does not solve the exact problem in the OP.  But, modifying this code to actually find the n'th ENF number is pretty simple.  Making 
repeated callse to `countENF`, we first figure out how many digits the n'th ENF number has, 
and then, one digit at a time, we figure out the digits of the n'th ENF from left to right.

```
 public static String getNthENF(BigInteger i){
    int k = i.toString().length();
    HashMap results = new HashMap();
    List<String> powers = getPowers(k);
    while(countENF("",k,results,powers).compareTo(i) < 0){
      k++;
     powers = getPowers(k);
    }
    String solution = "";
    BigInteger total = new BigInteger("0");

    while(solution.length() < k){
      for(String d : digits){
        BigInteger newTotal = total.add(countENF(solution + d,k,results,powers));
        int comp = newTotal.compareTo(i);
        if(comp >= 0){
          solution = solution + d;
          break;
        }
        total = newTotal;
      }
    }
    return solution;
  }
```

Here is some sample output, giving the N'th ENF as computed using dynamic programming, as well as using brute force, for powers of 10.

```
Dynamic Programming:
10^1: 118
10^2: 1178
10^3: 11680
10^4: 115730
10^5: 1146628
10^6: 11360558
10^7: 112558960
10^8: 1115229050
10^9: 11049731548
10^10: 103258311161
10^11: 935443232311
10^12: 8576360477119
10^13: 79330786951511
10^14: 732117130575070
10^15: 6880811638385388
10^16: 64284911460844887
10^17: 610616803411054857
10^18: 5759459802926457113
10^19: 54555977711878792498
10^20: 518773721711219891634
Brute Force:
10^1: 118
10^2: 1178
10^3: 11680
10^4: 115730
10^5: 1146628
10^6: 11360558
10^7: 112558960
```

Comment: Sorry, but this is not very clear. Describe an algorithm for the OPs solution (not for something else stating that it can be modified), and prove its time complexity.

Comment: What is unclear about it?  I've explained the basic algorithm in pseudocode, and then I've given explicit java code which will solves the OP's exact problem.  I haven't proven the time complexity, that is true, although it is pretty clear that it runs in time polynomial to the number of digits.  Experimentally, the running time seems to be `O(n^4.5)`, although this might be improvable.  I'm not claiming this is the fastest possible algorithm, but it is certainly much better than brute force.

Comment: It's a shame that this answer got only half of the bounty amount and that the full bounty was not awarded!

Answer (score 1):

#### Edit: This approach misses the eleven-non-free number 1011 for example. I know what's wrong and will fix it, but can't do it now.

Let's take a principled approach that builds up to the solution rather than trying to handle it all at once.

Let S be the sequence of powers of 11:

11, 121, 1331, 14641, 161051, ...

Let E(n) be the set of numbers that contain the string representation of n as a substring. The set you are looking for is the union of E(n) over n in S.

How do we generate the elements of E(n) for some n? (Let's take n = 121 for example.)

Make a directed acyclic graph where n is the root node. Make n point to all 19 of the following numbers:

Append 0-9: n0 n1 n2 n3 n4 n5 n6 n7 n8 n9
Prepend 1-9: 1n 2n 3n 4n 5n 6n 7n 8n 9n

Repeat the process for each of these new nodes. Notice that certain nodes may end up with more than one parent, so you'll want to maintain a hashmap from number to node pointer.  (You can get to 71217 by 121 -> 1217 -> 71217 or 121 -> 7121 -> 71217.)

This graph has the property that, for any edge from u to v, we have u < v. This is important because it means we can generate the elements of E(n) in increasing order by doing a breadth-first generation of the graph, always expanding the unexpanded node with smallest number.

Now merge these graphs for all n in S.

You have one large directed acyclic graph (that is infinite) that you can generate in a breadth-first manner, always expanding the unexpanded node with smallest number, emitting the next (kth) eleven-non-free number.

## Pseudocode

*It works, I tested it. Here's a C# gist: https://gist.github.com/timothy-shields/8026924*

```
procedure generate_eleven_non_free
i = 1
n = 11^i
//frontier nodes; F.insert(x) does nothing if x already in F
F = empty-min-heap-set
while (true)
{
    if (F.empty() or F.min() > n)
    {
        F.insert(n)
        i = i + 1
        n = 11^i
    }
    else
    {
        m = F.extractmin()
        yield m
        for j = 0:9        
            F.insert(append(m,j))
        for j = 1:9
            F.insert(append(j,m))
    }
}
```

To get the kth eleven-non-free number, simply do something like generate_eleven_non_free().element_at(k), where this is supposed to pick out the kth yielded number.

Comment: Actually I think this can work if we can have a relation where the elements that are at the same level in the tree are also guaranteed to be in increasing/decreasing order. Otherwise the number of elements shall grow exponentially at the power of 19 at each level.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal That the number of elements grows exponentially is perfectly fine. If you're looking for the kth eleven-non-free number you will still only need to generate O(k) nodes in the graph.

Comment: See if k = 21. Then won't you need to generate 19*19 nodes in the worst case since you are not differentiating between elements at the same level?

Comment: @AbhishekBansal When I say you will only have to generate O(k) nodes, that means it's bounded by ck where c is a constant, approximately 19. Think carefully about it - this is definitely a correct O(k) space/time solution.

Comment: Ok now I see. Still I feel it would be better if somehow the nodes that are generated at the same level are forcibly generated in ascending order.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal I think you're not properly perceiving the way this works. The constant 19 is not the problem. If anything is the problem, it's the asymptotic complexity of O(k). You could hope for something sublinear, but I don't immediately see how to beat this.

Comment: **This is no better than brute force solution**. You just basicly generate all superstrings of powers of 11, and then use some way to sort them up. So you have `log k` DAGs, each one of  `O(k)` nodes, which results in `O(k log k)` total complexity. *The same complexity can be achieved much easier by simply generating all superstrings of powers of 11 to array and sort them and remove duplicates.* And last, this has exactly the *same complexity as the most simple brute force solution*, i.e. traversing all numbers. See my answer for more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

`10^18` is really, really big. Brute force is not your friend.

However, let us note some conveniences:

- If a string `s` represents a eleven-non-free number, then trivially so does `d s` (where `d` is a string of digits).
- If you wanted to know how many `k`-digit numbers are eleven-non-free, you could base that off of how many `k-1`-digit numbers are eleven-non-free.
- (e.g. how many 1xx numbers are eleven-non-free? Well, how many xx numbers are eleven-non-free? Obviously at least that many 1xx numbers are eleven-non-free.. The only additional cases are when a power of eleven starts with the digit at the start -- with the 1 that just got tacked on the front.)
- This suggests a relatively straightforward dynamic programming approach to figure out how many eleven-non-free numbers are in a string of known length with a fixed prefix. (e.g. how many eleven-non-free numbers are in 934xxxxx)

Finally, throw some binary-search style logic on top, and you should be able to find exactly which number is the N-th eleven-non-free number.

Comment: I've skipped a lot of explanation in the hopes that this gives you the "push" you need to solve the problem. If you'd like a more explicit answer, please state so.

Comment: I think you also need to consider suffixes - i.e. `x s y` instead if your `x s`, where either `x` or `y` can be empty (but not both, because you already know the status of `s`). Otherwise you might miss things like `112`...

Comment: The notion here is we're tacking on a prefix to a known class of strings. That is, we know that there is exactly one eleven-non-free number for two-digit numbers (i.e. numbers of form xx). If we want to examine numbers of form 1xx we would have to only add cases where powers of eleven start at the newly added '1' since all the suffix cases are already handled. Hence, there's no reason to consider suffixes separately. (hence we'd be looking to see if 11 and 121 can appear in 1xx, and if so, would the number already be counted?)

Comment: Yes, but you're building that class of strings by considering strings that are already in the class. If you start with `{11, 121, ...}`, how would you ever determine `112` belongs in the class if you don't consider suffixes? I agree if you know that `112` is already in the class, then any prefix you add should also produce a member of the class, but if you only consider prefixes, you're not generating the full set. You need to consider cases where there's a prefix as well as cases where there's a suffix, and cases where there's both a prefix and a suffix.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a divide and conquer algorithm to me.

This problem feels very similar to: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/divide-and-conquer-maximum-sum-subarray/

and this:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem

When you divide you split the original String s into 2 parts that are roughly 1/2 as big.  At the bottom of your recursion you have easy problems with small 1 char Strings that are all eleven-free (because they don't contain enough chars to have any powers of 11 inside).

The "trick" comes in when you "step up" in the recursion.  In this step you need to take advantage of the fact that any "power" (i.e. 121) you are looking for MUST bridge the "middle" of the input string.

For example, when you "step up" from Strings of length 1 to Strings of length 2 you'll know that some of the power you're looking for is in the first half, and some is in the second half of the input string.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an `O(klog^2(k))` algorithm:

```py
def add(vals, new_vals, m, val):
    if val < m and val not in vals and val not in new_vals:
        new_vals.append(val)

def kth11(k):
    vals = [ 11**i for i in range(1, k+1) ]
    new_vals = [ ]
    while True:
        vals = sorted(vals + new_vals)
        vals = vals[:k]
        m = vals[-1]
        new_vals = [ ] 
        for v in vals:
            for s in range(1, 10):
                val = int(str(s) + str(v))
                add(vals, new_vals, m, val)
            for s in range(0, 10):
                val = int(str(v) + str(s))
                add(vals, new_vals, m, val)
        if len(new_vals) == 0: break
    return vals[-1]

print kth11(130)
```

Answer (score 0):

`given a k, find the kth eleven-non-free number.`...
is a big question.

Since this is time taking question, I am writing pseudo code.

1. **First step** Keep the powers of eleven handy

`var eleven_powers = [];
for (var i=0; i<1000; i++)
   eleven_powers.push(Math.pow(11,i));`

1. **Second Step** Keep all possible `non-eleven-free` numbers to an extent you can. This will have to deal with big integers.

`for (var i=11; i<Integer.MAX_VALUE; i++){
    if(string(i).substring(for each of eleven_powers) == true)
    store it sequentially results_array
}`

1. **Third Step** `Take k, return results_array[k]`