# Count the number of Ks between 0 and N

Tags: algorithm, numbers, range, time-complexity, counting

## Problem:

I have seen questions like:

1. [`count the number of 0s between 0 and N?`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11891984/count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-0s-in-integers-from-1-to-n)
2. [`count the number of 1s between 0 and N?`](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/47477/number-of-occurrences-of-the-digit-1-in-the-numbers-from-0-to-n)
3. [`count the number of 2s between 0 and N?`](https://sites.google.com/site/spaceofjameschen/home/recursion/compute-number-of-2s-in-a-range-of-0-n)
4. ... ...

These kinds of questions are very similar of asking to find the total number that `Ks (i.e. K=0,1,2,...,9)` are shown in number range `[0, N]`.

Example:

- Input:  `K=2, N=35`
- Output: `14`
- Detail: list of `2`s between `[0,35]`: `2, 12, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 32`, note that `22` will be counted as twice (as `22` contains two `2`s)

---

## What we have:

There are solutions for each of them (available if you search for it). Usually, `O(log N)` time is needed to solve such questions by recursively taking the highest digit into consideration, and so on. One example of counting the number of 2s between 0 and N can be solved by the following procedure (borrowed from [here](http://tianrunhe.wordpress.com/2012/06/04/count-the-number-of-2s-between-0-and-n/)):

```
// Take n = 319 as example => 162
int numberOf2sBetween0AndN(int n) 
{
    if (n < 2)
        return 0;

    int result = 0;
    int power10 = 1;
    while (power10 * 10 < n)
        power10 *= 10;

    // power10 = 100
    int msb = n / power10; // 3
    int reminder = n % power10; // 19

    /*** Count # of 2s from MSB ***/
    if (msb > 2)    // This counts the first 2 from 200 to 299
        result += power10;
    if (msb == 2)   // If n = 219, this counts the first 2 from 200 to 219 (20 of 2s).
        result += reminder + 1;

    /*** Count # of 2s from reminder ***/
    // This (recursively) counts for # of 2s from 1 to 100; msb = 3, so we need to multiply by that.
    result += msb * numberOf2s(power10);
    // This (recursively) counts for # of 2s from 1 to reminder
    result += numberOf2s(reminder);

    return result;
}
```

---

## Question:

Note that, we cannot simply change all `2`s part in the above code to `1`s in order to solve the problem of counting the number of `1`s between `0` and `N`. It seems that we have to handle differently (not trivial) for different cases.

***Is there a general procedure we can follow to handle all `K`s (i.e. `K=0,1,2,...,9`), i.e. something like the following function?***

```
int numberOfKsBetween0AndN(int k, int n)
```

---

## Test cases:

Here are some test cases if you want to check your solution:

- `k=1, N=1`: 1
- `k=1, N=5`: 1
- `k=1, N=10`: 2
- `k=1, N=55`: 16
- `k=1, N=99`: 20
- `k=1, N=10000`: 4001
- `k=1, N=21345`: 18821
- `k=2, N=10`: 1
- `k=2, N=100`: 20
- `k=2, N=1000`: 300
- `k=2, N=2000`: 601
- `k=2, N=2145`: 781
- `k=2, N=3000`: 1900

Comment: Isn't this from projecteuler.net [again](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20662171/684229)? These problems should be your own work.

Comment: @Tomas No, it's not. I just want to check if these problems can be solved in a more general way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe this is what's your need, simple, general and fast.

Below is an example in Python:

### Slow Checker

The checker is simple, use `string` to find all number in string from '0' - 'n', and count the match times of `k`, it's slow but we can use it to check other solutions.

```
import string       

def knChecker( k, n ):
    ct = 0
    k = str(k)
    for i in xrange(0,n+1):
        ct += string.count(str(i),k)
    return ct
```

### Fast and General Solution

#### k ≠ 0

for every k = [1,9],it's much clear that in [0,9] we can find 1 match in first bit;

in [0,99] we can find 1 matches in first bit and 10 matches in second bit, so all is 1*10^1 + 10*10^0 = 20 matches,

in [0,999] we can find 1 matches in first bit ,10 matches in second bit and 100 matches in third bit, so all is 1*10^2 + 10*10^1 + 100*10^0 = 300 matches...

So we can easily conclude that in [0,10^l - 1], there is `l * 10^(l-1)` matches.

More general, we can find in [0,f * 10^l - 1], there `f*10^(l-1) * l` matches.

So here is the solution:

for example, n = 'abcd', k = 'k'

- step1: if n = 0 or n = '', return 0; count matches in 'a000', use the up formula, l = len(n)
- step2A: if a == k, we know all 'bcd' is matched, so add `bcd` matches.
- step2B: if a > k, we know all 'k***' is matched, so add `10^(l-1)` matches.
- step3: cut the first bit a, and set n = 'bcd', go to step1

Here is the code for k ≠ 0:

```
def knSolver( k, n ):
    if k == '0':
        return knSolver0( n, 0 )
    if not n:
        return 0
    ct = 0
    n = int(n)
    k = int(k)
    l = len(str(n))
    f = int(str(n)[:1])
    if l > 1:
        ct += f * 10 ** (l-2) * (l-1)
    if f > k:
        ct += 10 ** (l-1)
    elif f == k:
        ct += n - f * 10 ** (l-1) + 1
    return ct + knSolver( k, str(n)[1:])
```

#### k = 0

k = 0 is a bit of tricky, because `0***` is equal to `***` and will not allowed to count it marches '0'.

So solution for k ≠ 0 can't fit k = 0. But the idea is similar.

We can find that if n < 100, there must be `n/10 + 1` matches.

if n in [100,199], it's much similar that as k ≠ 0 in [0,99], has 20 matches;

if n in [100,999], it's much similar that as k ≠ 0 in [100,999], has 20 * 9 matches;

if n in [1000,9999], it's much similar that as k ≠ 0 in [1000,9999], has 300 * 9 matches...

More general, if n in [10^l,k*10^l-1], it will has `l*10^(l-1)*k` matches.

So here is the solution:

for example, n = 'abcd', k = '0', recurse step `s` = 0

- step0: if n = '', return 0; if n < 100, return `n/10+1`;
- step1A: n='f(...)', f is first bit of n. if s > 0, say we have handled the first bit before, so 0 can treat as k ≠ 0, so if f == 0, all rest (...) should match, just add (...)+1 matches.
- step1B: if s > 0 and f > 0, l = len(n), we know there will be `10 ** (l-1)` matched in the first bit of `0(...)`, and (l-1) * 10 ** (l-2) in `(...)`
- step2: if s == 0, count matches in 'f(...)-1', use the up formula
- step3: if s > 0, just check for (...) as s == 0 in step2, will get `(f-1) * 10 ** (l-2) * (l-1)`, (f-1), because we can't start form `0***`.
- step4: cut the first bit f, and set n = '(...)', s += 1, go to step1

Here is the code of k = 0:

```
def knSolver0( n, s ):
    if n == '':
        return 0
    ct = 0
    sn = str(n)
    l = len(sn)
    f = int(sn[:1])
    n = int(n)
    if n < 100 and s == 0:
        return n / 10 + 1
    if s > 0 and f > 0:
        ct += 10 ** (l-1) + (l-1) * 10 ** (l-2)
    elif s > 0 and f == 0:
        ct += n + 1
    if n >= 100 and s == 0:
        ct += 10
        for i in xrange(2,l):
            if i == l-1:
                ct += i * 10 ** (i-1) * (f-1)
            else:
                ct += i * 10 ** (i-1) * 9
    elif s > 0 and f != 0:
        ct += (f-1) * 10 ** (l-2) * (l-1)
    return int(ct + knSolver0( sn[1:], s+1 ))
```

### Test

```
print "begin check..."
for k in xrange(0,10):
    sk = str(k)
    for i in xrange(0,10000):
        #knSolver( sk, i )
        if knChecker( sk, i ) != knSolver( sk, i ):
            print i, knChecker( sk, i ) , knSolver( sk, i )
print "check end!"
```

Test all k[0,9] from n[0,10000], it passed all cases.

The test will take a bit long time, because of the checker is slow. If remove the checker, all cases in my laptop take about one second.

Comment: @herohuyongtao Updated~

Comment: Thanks for your update. For the code for `k≠0`, it works for most cases. However, it will fail when `k=2, n=2000`, result should be `600` instead of `601`. Please have a check.

Comment: @herohuyongtao I might say k=2,n=2000 is 601, because of the checker, what is your result when k=2,n=1999?

Comment: 600 for `k=2, n=1999`.

Comment: @herohuyongtao So, that's much clear, 601 is for `k=2,n=2000`, `2000` has one `2` matched.

Answer (score 5):

It can be done arithmetically.

EDIT

*I didn't see your code example at first. My code is very similar, except inputs are parametrized. So the answer is Yes, it can be  generalized, but you need to handle 0 as special case.*

If the given number N is two digits number, let's say AB and we are counting digit K (1..9).

> ```
> IF B is less than K THEN 0 ELSE 1
> IF A is less than K THEN A ELSE A + 10
> ```

Your example Input: K=2, N=35

```
5 is greater than 2 -> count = 1 (this is digit 2 in number 32)
3 is greater than 2 -> count += 3 (this are twos in 2, 12, 22) + 10 (this are 20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29)
*22 is counted twice
```

so we count 1 + 3 + 10 = 14 twos

C# Code example (n = 1..99, k = 1..9):

```
int numberOfKsBetween0AndN (int n, int k)        
{
    int power = 1;
    int counter = 0;

    while (n > 0)
    {
        int d = n % 10;
        n /= 10;

        counter += (d < k ? 0 : power) + d * power / 10;
        power *= 10;
    }

   return counter;
}
```

Improved code for n > 100

UPDATE

> There was an error in condition I didn't take in account digits when d
>   is equal to k, for k=2, N=2145 my algorithm didn't take in account
>   fist digit two in 2000..2145. Now it works as it should (pass all tests):

```
    int numberOfKsBetween0AndN (int n, int k)   
    { 
        int originalNumber = n;
        int power = 1;
        int i = 0;
        int counter = 0;            

        while (n > 0)
        {
            int d = n % 10;
            n /= 10;

            counter += d * (power * i) / 10;

            if (d > k)
                counter += power;
            else if (d == k)
                counter += originalNumber % power + 1;

            power *= 10;
            i++;
        }

        return counter;
    }
```

UPDATE 2

For k=0 (including 0 and n) is easier, you just need to count numbers divisible by 10, 100, 1000, etc.

```
int numberOf0sBetween0AndN(int n)
{
    int power = 1;            
    int counter = 1;

    while(power < n)
    {                
        power *= 10;
        counter += n / power;
    }

    return counter;
}
```

Comment: Your code will fail in some cases. For example, for `n=100, k=2`, the result should be 20 while your code will give 10.

Comment: Yes you are right, it works for n = 1..99 and k = 1..9. So for n=99 and k = 2 will return 20 as expected.

Comment: Any idea on how to extend this function to handle large numbers?

Comment: Can you check results now? Updated code should work for arbitrary n.

Comment: Thanks for the update. However, it will still fail for e.g. case `n=2000, k=2`, which should be 600 instead of 1600.

Comment: Can you define test cases? I will try to make it work. There was error in condition instead of (d < k ? 0 : power), condition should be (d <= k ? 0 : power).

Comment: I tested your updated version. It works for most cases. But still, it will fail for `K=2, N=2145` or simpler case `K=1, N=1`.

Comment: Good work by solving it iteratively. Can you also share your code for `k=0`?

Comment: @Branimir nice work. If you have time, can you explain the solution a little bit? Like how are you solving the problem? The though process?

Comment: @saadi Thank you. I tried to explain the thought process in the first part of the answer. If you have some specific question I'll try to answer.

In general, try to write down an example and solve it manually on paper. After you solve a few examples manually, a pattern may show up, test if it is a general solution. Practice helps too :)

Answer (score 1):

It's simple. Any number can be represented in a special record:

73826 = 9999 + 6*(9999 + 1) + (3826 + 1)

You will need to count the number of these figures for the numbers 9, 99, 999, 9999 ... Then you can put them in the array. Special case - by 0, it uses an array [1, 11, 111, 1111, ...]

Keep in mind that the first digit so also may contain the required value.

Comment: Please explain more on how to count the number of different `K's` for e.g. 9999. I am more curious about this.

Comment: 9999 = 999 + 8*(999 + 1) + 999 + 1


Depending on the numbers that you need.

Comment: Any link to the mathematics behind this would be appreciated as I cannot grok it quiet yet. Seems to me like all you're doing is 73286 = 7*10000+3286 except you split the 7*10000 as 6*(9999+1) + 999 + 1 (which you add with 3286)

Answer (score 1):

For case 0, we need to handle separately,

For general case from 1 to 9:

Assume that we know the **number** contains  k that has **x digits** and called it **m**, to calculate all number contains k and has **(x + 1) digits**, the formula will be :

```
9*m + (all_number_has_x_digit - m)
```

The reason is simple, to all number that already contains k, we can insert 1 to 9 as first digit,so we have 9*m. For all number that doesn't contains k, we can add k in front of them, which created all_number_has_x_digit - m).

To calculate the number of k appears from all these numbers, the formula should be similar, (By maintaining **both values** : the amount of numbers that contain k and the number of appearances of k)  this is just an idea for you to start :)

Comment: How to understand the formula? Will it hold for all `K's`?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it if you convert the integers to Strings and match the String 'k' in a loop through that array.

Comment: Can you share more details? To me, it seems it's an `O(N log N)` approach.

Comment: You can even count every digit in a single pass: build a map for the counters, and use the string's characters as a key. You might as well use an array and calculate the current character's index via something like `c - '0'`.

Comment: It's a slow approach esp. if n is very large. It's basically O(nm) where m is the size of digit.

Answer (score -1):

The simplest solution this problem is using regular expression.

```
//_k --> pattern
//_n range

Regex r = new Regex(_k.ToString(), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        int count = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i <= _n; i++)
        {
            MatchCollection m = r.Matches(i.ToString());
            foreach(Match _m in m)
            { 
            if (_m.Success)
            {
                count += 1;
            }
            }

        }

        Console.WriteLine(count);
```