# Javascript Loop Performance: Counting occurrences of a number in a finite series

Tags: javascript, performance, loops, math, mathematical-optimization

What is the most efficient way to write a **javascript loop** to **calculate** the number of **occurrences of 7's** (as an example number) that will be encountered in **counting from 1 to 100**?

**Example:**

```
function numberOccurences(targetNumber, minNumber, maxNumber) {

var count = 0;
for (i = minNumber; i < maxNumber; i++) {
    count = count + (i.toString().split(targetNumber).length - 1);     
}
return count;
}

var result = numberOccurences(7,1,100);
```

Comment: Which performance problems are you experiencing with your solution? I mean, it does not even run because numbers don't have a `split` method. Can't get faster than that :P

Comment: Is the targetNumber any number, or always a single digit? What do you mean by occurrences?

Comment: If you care for effeciency, just don't use a loop.

Comment: @FelixKling fixed...I just want to know the fastest way. :)

Comment: Surely somebody a little better at elementary number theory than me can come up with a closed-form solution to this problem. (Or something pretty close.)

Comment: Well, in the numbers between zero and 100 (`[0,100)`), one encounters 21 sevens: `07, 17, 27, 37, 47, 57, 67, 77, 87, 97, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 78, 79`. I think that in a range from 0 to any power of 10, it's something like `log10(max) * 10 + log10(max) - 1`

Comment: wait that's not quite right; the second part is more complicated and is probably a combinatorial term.

Comment: @Pointy: I count 20 sevens in that string.

Comment: @Bergi I have a lifelong awful track record of off-by-one errors :)

Comment: @Pointy Yeah with the provided example numbers the answer should return a count of 20. Good catch! :)

Answer (score 4):

This will do it without looking at the actual numbers. Sorry, no loop, but you did ask for effeciency. If you really want to use a loop, make the recursion an iteration.

```
function digitOccurences(digit, min, max, base) {
    if (typeof base != "number") base = 10;
    return digitOccurencesPlus(digit, max, base, 1, 0) - digitOccurencesPlus(digit, min, base, 1, 0);

    function digitOccurencesPlus(digit, N, base, pow, rest) {
        if (N == 0) return 0;
        var lastDigit = N%base,
            prevDigits = (N-lastDigit)/base;
        var occsInLastDigit = pow*(prevDigits+(lastDigit>digit));
        var occsOfLastInRest = rest * (lastDigit==digit);
        // console.log(prevDigits+" "+lastDigit, rest, occsInLastDigit, occsOfLastInRest);
        return occsInLastDigit + occsOfLastInRest + digitOccurencesPlus(digit, prevDigits, base, pow*base, pow*lastDigit+rest);
     }
}
```

Comment: [Quick jsperf](http://jsperf.com/occurences-count) against the for-loop solution from one of the other answers.

Comment: Note to all the upvoters: Please stop upvoting non-working solutions. Note to self: Stop prematurely posting non-tested solutions.

Comment: @MobileFire: You're testing the speed of declaring a function? Interesting, but completely irrelevant.

Comment: Not sure this works, I'm testing it myself but getting 0 back for `digitOccurences(7,0,100)`

Comment: @wvandaal: Sorry, I've updated it 4 mins ago. It is now working and correctly yields `20`.

Comment: @Bergi I believe the answer for `digitOccurences(7,0,100)` should be 19

Comment: @wvandaal: `"7,17,27,37,47,57,67,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,87,97".match(/7/g).length == 20`

Comment: @Bergi duh, you're right, totally forgot to count 77 twice

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting problem, and already has similar answers for other languages. Maybe you could try to make this one in javascript: [Count the number of Ks between 0 and N](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20945790/count-the-number-of-ks-between-0-and-n)

That solution is for occurences from 0 to n, but you could easily use it to calculate from a to b this way:

`occurences(a,b)= occurences(0,b)-occurences(0,a)`

Comment: Thanks for the link, it helped me figure out a correct solution. Also I've used the same solution for coping with the `min` parameter :-)

Comment: @juvian: Have a look at the third revision of my answer above :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is much faster (**x6**) than my original function...[JSPERF](http://jsperf.com/number-instance-counts)

```
function numberOccurences2(targetNumber, minNumber, maxNumber) { 
var strMe = "";
for (i = minNumber; i < maxNumber; i++) {
    strMe = strMe.concat(i);
}
var re = new RegExp(targetNumber,"g");
var num1 = strMe.length;
var num2 = strMe.replace(re, "").length;
num2 = num1- num2;
return (num2);
}
```

There has to be a faster way still...

Comment: I can't be believe this is faster, this must be horribly eating memory. Astonishing.